# ImageView -> getScaling / position of image (where does scaling happen)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I want to get the exact position and size or at least the scaling of the image contained in an ImageView, because I need another ImageView on top of it with the same size for drawing.

My original image is about 1680x1050 and is displayed on an imageview with "fitcenter" as scaling type. It is scaled correctly.

I tried different things to get the scaling/bounds of the drawn image:

`imgv.getDrawable().getBounds();`  returns the original size of the image (1680x1050)
`imgv.getDrawingRect(outRect);`  gets me the size of the imageview, but not the size of it's content
`imgv.getScaleX();`  returns 1.0, how can that be? (image is scaled correctly and about 1000x500px)
`imgv.getMatrix().getValues(values);
           float scaleX = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
           float scaleY = values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];`  also says there is no scaling applied, why?

I'm a little desperate right now and would really appreciate your help.

**Where is the scaling and positioning happening and how do I get it?**

---

EDIT, additional info:

The content of the ImageView is created like this:

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgWidth, imgHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
imgv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

Afterwards I do both, drawing on the canvas and setting the pixels of the bitmap directly with bitmap.setPixels(....) followed by ImageView.invalidate.